# Coustom chain works well but not shown with `iptables -L`

Tags: linux, iptables

To do some forwarding jobs, I use a script to add a custom chain. Part of the code is here (run as root):

```sh
iptables -t nat -N v2ray_forwarder
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -j v2ray_forwarder
iptables -t nat -A v2ray_forwarder -p tcp -m set --match-set srv_ip dst -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A v2ray_forwarder -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A v2ray_forwarder -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A v2ray_forwarder -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A v2ray_forwarder -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A v2ray_forwarder -p tcp -m set --match-set gfw_ip dst -j REDIRECT --to-port 1081
iptables -t nat -A v2ray_forwarder -p tcp -m set ! --match-set chn_ip dst -j REDIRECT --to-port 1081
```

The code works fine and I'm sure the packages have been correctly relayed. But, after I tap `sudo iptables -L`, it comes out:

```sh
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

On my router(OpenWRT), `iptables -L` always shows all chains exist, but it doesn't work on my laptop. Could someone tells me why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom chains is bound to a table. It means you cannot use a chain, that has been created in the `mangle` table, in rules of the `filter` or the `nat` tables.

The `iptables -L` command shows only the `filter` table chains. Check the output of `iptables -t nat -L`. But better use the `iptables-save -c` command to list the full rule set with counters.